# how to embed external webpage in my wordpress page

Tags: embed

I have two pages to embed within my WP site.

Both contain data from an external site which runs our events management database. This data is presented on two pages - one for catering menus offered to our customers, the other is an inquiry/contact form.

Two page links are given for embedding into my site. The information submitted by the customer on either page is collected onto our database within the third party site.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You could simply iframe the content into your pages?

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

Some more info on iframe params are here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Otherwise a nicer alternative might be to show the external pages via a modal window (which is still essentially an iframe).

You could try Fancybox (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples), there are iframe examples and code on the page, but it's quite simple, once you've included the relevant files you just use

```
<a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="/demo/iframe.html">Iframe</a>
```

Then the JS would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
```

});